# Changing grayscale effect based on ranger/slider

Tags: javascript, html

I want the grayscale effect to increase when the ranger value is increased.

```js
function change() {
  const img = document.querySelector(".image");
  const slider = document.querySelector(".range");
}
```

```html
<input onchange="change()" type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
<img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499195333224-3ce974eecb47?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1248&q=80" alt="">
```

A bit new to this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `grayscale` as shown below value, and also change the event from `onchange` to `oninput` so that it is updated as soon as the slider is moved.

```js
function change() {
  const img = document.querySelector(".image");
  const slider = document.querySelector(".range");
  img.style.filter = `grayscale(${slider.value}%)`
}
```

```html
<input oninput="change()" type="range" class="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
<img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499195333224-3ce974eecb47?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1248&q=80" alt="">
```

Comment: `onchange` will only trigger when the slider is let go. Wheras `oninput` will trigger whenever the slider is moved or changed in anyway.